# How to make a single column refers to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have 4 tables here, their relationship is like the following:
[image]

For 'band' table, I have 4 columns: id, band_name, first_name, last_name. (first_name and last_name refer to columns in 'independent artist' table).

For 'independent artist' I have 3 columns: id, first_name, last_name.

For 'act' table, I have 3 column: id, performer, music. Here for the perfumer, I want to refer to both band and independent artist table.

For 'music' table, I have 3 columns: id, song_name, release_year.

I also predict future changes here, for instance if a team member in a band wants to change his last name, it will affect both the 'band' and 'independent artist' table.

Intuitively I think my solution is not good, can anyone provide better design for the tables? Thanks.

Comment: How about just have an `artist` table with a `name`, and a flag that indicates if they're independent or not.

Comment: Do you mean I merge the 'band' and 'independent artist' table? If so, there would be null values for first_name and last_name if the artist is a band otherwise the band_name would be null. Correct me if I misunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: Yea, I don't see a compelling reason to have two separate tables for this.  Especially if an `act` needs to refer to either a band or artist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

Band table:

- band_id PK
- band_name

Artist table:

- artist_id PK
- first_name
- last_name

Band_members table:

- band_id FK
- artist_id FK

Acts table:

- act_id PK
- band_id FK

Music table:

- music_id PK
- song_name
- release_year

Act_Contents table:

- act_id FK
- music_id FK

There's no need for a separate `Independent Artists` table. Just treat them as a band with just one member. And you should always use an ID as the foreign key, so you don't have to worry about updating references if an attribute changes; you just change it in one place, and the references are unaffected.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I would like to merge Acts and Act_contents table into one, would it be any disadvantages by doing this?

Comment: It's not normalized, because you'll have to repeat the `band_id` on every row.

Comment: Hi Barmar, does it mean if I want to do some selection like 'select the song by an artist', I would have to do like the following: 'select song_name from music, act_contents, acts, band, band_member, artist where music.music_id = act_contents.music_id and .. and band_members.artist_id = artist.id'?

Comment: Yes. When you normalize your data properly, it's often necessary to join lots of tables to get the answers to questions.

Comment: If you frequently need to refer to combinations of tables, create views for them.

Comment: My only concern with this is if band members change over time, you've no way to know history, so maybe a start/end date on the band_members table; or if band names change... So if history is a concern, you need to think about the design a bit more or have a journal/history for everything.

Comment: Temporal databases require lots of different design.

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. I don't understand which NF will I break if I merge Acts and Act_contents table, as it is that there will be repeated band_id in many rows after merging, but it does not break any NFs. Correct me if I am wrong. thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the normal forms, but I think it violates 2nd Normal Form.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a one-to-many relation between `band` and `artist` where a band may reference one or more artists (by id or artist). That way the first name, and last name stay in the `artist` table and are not duplicated in the `band` table.

As for the other problem that you are having - you can't reference columns from more than one foreign table in a relationship. You'd have to model that by either creating two columns in the `Act` table, one that references `band` and one that references `artist` and add a constraint that only one may be non-null, or something else.

That said, you may want to [take a look at MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Database/Schema) for inspiration. I've worked with that database in the past and the project is being developed by lots of smart people that have worked on the model for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You sad it - you need a `performer` linked to `act`, not `band` or `artist`. I mean you need an abstraction about the object linked to the `act` object. The `performer` will be then linked first to the `band` object and second to the `artist`. You'll need to determine grammatically if a performer is a band or an independent artist depending on the present link to one of both objects. 
 And of course you need a many-to-many relation between band and artist.
Something like this:

```
band(id PK, name)
artist(id PK, first_name, last_name)
band_artists(band_id, artist_id)
performer(id PK, band_id, artist_id)
act(id PK, performer_id, music_id)
music(id, song_name, release_year)
```

I would not recommend you to use only one object for both band and artist because they have different meaning and own life. In the future you may want to add some physical characteristics to the artist for instance that are not relevant to a bad and so on.

It will be easy to know when a performer is a band or an artist. In the first case you'll have a non-NULL value for the band_id field. In the second you'll have a NULL value in the band_id and non-NULL value in the artist_id field.

If you need to retrieve an information about the performer related to a song for example you can do it in the following way:

```
SELECT 
    music.song_name, 
    performer.id as performer_id, 
    group.name as group_name,
    artist.first_name,
    artist.second_name
FROM music 
    LEFT JOIN act on music.id = act.music_id
    LEFT JOIN performer on act.performer_id = performer.id
    LEFT JOIN band on performer.band_id = band.id
    LEFT JOIN artist on performer.artist_id = artist.id
```

Now if your program logic you need to `calculate` the performer name:

```
if performer.band_name is not None:
    performer.name = performer.band_name
else:
    performer.name = performer.first_name + ' ' + performer.last_name
```

I believe the example code is self explanatory even itś not in your programming language and given there is some preprocessing of the query's result to obtain the `performer` object used in the example.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have a question here, if I want to select a song ant its performer, how would I do it with SQL, need I do some if-else-like selecting?

Comment: No, you can have just one query selecting all the information about the performer you would need. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation! I hope I could upvote twice

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like the following.

There is an act that is either an individual artist or a band as indicated by the act_type (artist_id and band_id are both primary keys of their respective tables and a foreign key to act_id). A band is a collaboration of one or more individual artists, or may be a collaboration of more than one band, or a collaboration of one or more bands and one or more individual artists.

There is a recording that is either an individual song or an album/EP as indicated by the recording type (song_id and album_id are both primary keys or their respective tables and a foreign key to recording_id). An album/EP consists of more than one individual songs.

A song must be associated with an act. However, an album may not be associated with an act directly, such as a compilation album. There may be acts who do not release recordings by themselves but only as part of a band. A recording may or may not have a release date if they are not available by themselves but only as part of an album.

```
+---------------------+     +----------+                 +----------------+     +---------------------------+
| ACT_RELATIONSHIPS   |     | ACTS     |                 | RECORDINGS     |     | RECORDING_RELATIONSHIPS   |
+---------------------+     +----------+                 +----------------+     +---------------------------+
| act_relationship_id |-----| act_id   |-----------------| recording_id   |-----| recording_relationship_id |
| parent_act_id       |-----| act_type |                 | recording_type |-----| parent_recording_id       |
| child_act_id        |     +----------+                 | act_id         |     | child_recording_id        |
| start_date          |      |        |                  | release_date   |     +---------------------------+
| end_date            |      |        |                  +----------------+
+---------------------+      |        |                       |      |
                             |        |                       |      |
                  +-------------+  +-----------+    +-----------+  +------------+
                  | ARTISTS     |  | BANDS     |    | SONGS     |  | ALBUMS     |
                  +-------------+  +-----------+    +-----------+  +------------+
                  | artist_id   |  | band_id   |    | song_id   |  | album_id   |
                  | family_name |  | band_name |    | song_name |  | album_name |
                  | given_name  |  +-----------+    +-----------+  +------------+
                  +-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barmar's answer but I would add a extra column for independent_artist and that value would be a Yes or a No.

Artist Table:
*artist_id
*First_Name
*Last_Name
*Independent_Artist

Comment: I think Barmar's intention was there could be impossible for a column to refer to more than 1 columns, thus he suggested to treat independent artist and band with the same 'band', except that an independent artist is a band with only one member. For your suggestion, if an independent_artist column being added to the artist table, so that the artist table would be directly referred by the Acts table, it would come back to the original question: one column could not refer to more than 1 table at the same time. Correct me if I misunderstood, thank you :D

Comment: What if the artist performs both independently and as a member of a band?